# new array refers existing array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'd like to exchange value when its age over 30 and leave the existing one.
but they are both changed at the same time.
I think the new array refers existing one.
How do i separate them?

sorry for my description.

here's code:

```js
var arr = [
    {age:23},
    {age:25},
    {age:24},
    {age:30},
    {age:33},
    {age:24},
    {age:56},
    {age:13} 
];

var over30 = [];

 f = (array) =>{
     for(var i = 0 ; i<array.length; i++){
         if(array[i].age >= 30){
             let tmp = array[i];
             tmp.age +=1;
             over30.push(tmp);
         }
     }
 };
f(arr);
console.log(arr);
console.log(over30);
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO!
 What does _How do i separate them_ mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var arr = [
    {age:23},
    {age:25},
    {age:24},
    {age:30},
    {age:33},
    {age:24},
    {age:56},
    {age:13} 
];

var over30 = [];

 f = (array) =>{
     for(var i = 0 ; i<array.length; i++){
         if(array[i].age >= 30){
             let tmp = Object.assign({}, array[i]);
             tmp.age +=1;
             over30.push(tmp);
         }
     }
 };
f(arr);
console.log(arr);
console.log(over30);
```

Is this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a new object for the new array. You can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to make a copy of the initial object

```js
var arr = [
    {age:23},
    {age:25},
    {age:24},
    {age:30},
    {age:33},
    {age:24},
    {age:56},
    {age:13} 
];

var over30 = [];

 f = (array) =>{
     for(var i = 0 ; i<array.length; i++){
         if(array[i].age >= 30){
             // create a new object , modify it and push to new array
             let tmp = Object.assign({},array[i]);
             tmp.age +=1;
             over30.push(tmp);
         }
     }
 };
f(arr);
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
console.log(JSON.stringify(over30));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Arrays** and **Objects** are reference types. The easiest and fastest way is using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for cloning. In your case:

```
let tmp = {...array[i]};
```

Instead of

```
let tmp = array[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spread Operator or Object.assign for cloning

```
let over30 = [ ]   ,  temp = {} ;
arr.forEach(el => {
    if(el.age > 30){
        (temp = {...el}) ;   OR   temp = Object.assign( {} , el ) ;
        temp.age += 1 ;
        over30.push(temp) ; 
    }
}) ;

console.log(over30) ;  // [ { age: 34 }, { age: 57 } ]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let tmp = array[i];
```

There is a concept called shallow copy and deep copy. You are doing a shallow copy of object in `temp` which means temp hold the access to same location as `array[i]` at that point. It didn't copy the value, it copied the address of that index in array.  If you change value at `temp` you are automatically changing value of that `array index` as well.

you can either do

```
 let tmp = Object.assign({},array[i]);
```

which goes and get the value at index not the actual address of that index in array.

But this will only work for 1st level depth of objects. If the depth is more than one then you will need to convert the array to string using `JSON.stringify(array)` and then parse it again with `JSON.parse(array)` then it will work with any level of depth.

For more info about shallow copy and deep copy you can visit this link 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EeZBKv34mm4

Comment: You are right about shallow copy but the objects will still be the same references in each array

Comment: thank you! now i know the concept of deep copy and sallow copy

Comment: @charlietfl, you are right, i edited the code and fixed my mistake.

Answer (score -1):

```
var arr = [
    {age:23},
    {age:25},
    {age:24},
    {age:30},
    {age:33},
    {age:24},
    {age:56},
    {age:13},
];

const f = (array) => array.slice().filter((item)=>item.age>= 30).map((item)=>({...item}));

let over30 = f(arr);
console.log(arr);
console.log(over30);
```